# Informatica powercenter error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I'm facing an informatica powercenter error JAVA PLUGIN_1762 **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1** while executing a workflow with snowflake target table and Teradata source table.

I'm using informatica powercenter 10.2 HotFix1.

The target table was imported with "Create powerexchange for snowflake target" option on the Designer.

Have you any solution or idea on what is about ? please

Comment: There is insufficient information to give you a meaningful answer.  It could just be a bug in the software that you are using.  Powercenter appears to be a proprietary / closed source product, so there is probably little we could do to assist anyway.  I suggest that you contact the product support team.

Comment: You could also search the product's [knowledgebase](https://search.informatica.com/KBHome/) for articles that are relevant to your problem.

Comment: I have few questions - do you have license for power exchange for teradata and snowflake ? If yes,Pls add relevant part from session log. If no, you may be able to import but cant run any mapping. Alternative option is to use odbc for both source n target.